# Gameboy Processor LR35902 Opcode 0x08 Meaning

Tags: z80, gameboy

Could someone please explain what the opcode `0x08` does on the LR35902 processor. The mnemonic is `LD (a16),SP`.

I'm confused because the stack pointer is a 16-bit value but `(a16)` is an address to somewhere only capable of storing 8 bits (I think!). I could guess that the first 8 bits are placed into `(a16)` and the next are placed adjacent to those but I would like confirmation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that opcode puts SP value at an address (a16). Here's what it will look like:

```
void MemoryWrite(uint16_t addr, uint8_t value);

MemoryWrite(a16, SP & 0xFF);
MemoryWrite(a16 + 1, (SP & 0xFF00) >> 8);
```

Because it's a little-endian processor you put least significant byte first.

Comment: Thanks Creker, appreciated!

Comment: MemoryWrite((a16 + 1) & 0xFFFF, (SP & 0xFF00) >> 8);

Comment: Méga Lag, I see you are anding the address with 0xFFFF, which I believe is to make sure it is positive but I think this is implied by the notation a16. Also, even if I were to and with 0xFFFF shouldn't I do that before doing the + 1?

Comment: I don't think it's really necessary. First, don't think someone would make a game that writes to an address that would overflow uint16_t. Also, it would overwrite the stack which doesn't look like one would do. Second, uint16_t would just wrap around anyway, it's not an undefined behaviour.

Comment: @creker Correct! Upon execution of `LD (0xFFFF), SP`, the memory position `0xFFFF` will have SP least significant bits. Memory pointer wraps around and the CPU will attempt to write on memory position `0x0000`. Nothing would happen because `0x0000` is read-only.

Comment: Thank you for the info, now I know I didn't need to do that on my implementation x)

Comment: @GabrielOshiro, well, not quite read-only. It wouldn't overwrite anything but could trigger MBC. As you probably know, MBCs are programmed by writing into read-only addresses. For example, writing into 0x0000 would trigger external RAM in MBC1 and trigger RAM/RTC in MBC3. But emulator shouldn't check that anyway. You do what ROM tells you.